# Multiple images upload not working Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

i´m trying to upload multiple image with laravel but only the last image was uploaded

Controller

```
    $mobimage = new Mobimage;
    if ($request->has('image')){
        $file =  $request->file('image');
        foreach ($file as $files){

            $fileName = time().'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $files->move(public_path('smartphones'), $fileName);

            $mobimage->prodimage = $fileName;
            $mobimage->save();

        }


    }
```

blade

```
 <input name="image[]" id="exampleFile" type="file" multiple class="form-control-file">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move

```
$mobimage = new Mobimage;
```

after

```
 foreach ($file as $files){
```

line. Otherwise you create only single record and update it multiple times.